# Is traversing all elements in the (MVC) Model necessary every time it is updated?

Tags: d3.js

The code below is based on Bostock's [Circle Dragging I](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/22994cc97fefaeede0d861e6815a847e).

The original code updates the (MVC) Model while a circle is dragged. The argument `d` to the function `dragged` is the element of the array `circles` being dragged.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

    .active {
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }

</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        width = +svg.attr("width"),
        height = +svg.attr("height"),
        radius = 32;

    var circles = [
        {x: 100, y: 100},
        {x: 100, y: 200},
        {x: 100, y: 300}
    ];
    var lastIndex = 2;

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
                  .range(d3.schemeCategory20);

    svg.selectAll("circle")
       .data(circles)
       .enter().append("circle")
       .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
       .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
       .attr("r", radius)
       .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
       .call(d3.drag()
               .on("start", dragstarted)
               .on("drag", dragged)
               .on("end", dragended));

    function dragstarted(d) {
        d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
    }

    function dragged(d) {
        d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
    }

    function dragended(d) {
        d3.select(this).classed("active", false);
    }
    //----------------Addition----------------
    var click = function() {
        if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return;

        var p = d3.mouse(this),
            x = p[0],
            y = p[1];
        circles[++lastIndex] = {x: x, y: y};

        svg.append('circle')
           .attr('cx', x)
           .attr('cy', y)
           .attr('r', radius)
           .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(lastIndex); })
           .call(d3.drag()
                   .on("start", dragstarted)
                   .on("drag", dragged)
                   .on("end", dragended));
    };

    svg.on('click', click);

</script>
```

In the modification (under "addition"), the function `click` enables adding new circles, but the drag behavior is not active for the new points, presumably because unless a circle is added through `svg.data(circles).enter.append('circle')...`, D3.js does not keep a reference from the SVG circle back to the entry in the `circles` array.

A solution would be to put `svg.data(circles).enter.append('circle')...` in a function `refresh()` and call `refresh()` after the insertion of a new circle into tbe array `circles`.

Doing so means that when the array `circles` has `n` elements, it is traversed (in `n` steps) at the insertion of the `n+1`-th element.

Is there a way to insert a new circle with the drag behavior enabled, and keep the Model and the View in sync during dragging, without having to traverse `circles` at the insertion of each new circle?

Comment: Your  thinking is a bit off. The [`enter` selection](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_enter) only contains the records that have been newly introduced and were not previously being tracked by `d3`. It does not contain every single record.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I see your point. But just to find those extra elements, D3 matches the elements of circles with the existing SVG circles. Let me put it another way. Suppose `circles` is initially empty, and hence the initial `svg.selectAll("circle").data(circles)..` becomes superfluous, would we be able to append SVG circles through svg.append('circle')..call(d3.drag().on...` and get correct sync-ing of Model and View, or is a refresh after every insertion necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the `datum` of each new circle. That way, D3 can set the `d.x` and `d.y` when dragging:

```
svg.append('circle')
    .datum(circles[lastIndex])
    //etc...
```

Here is the updated code with that change only: http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/6dbf734683e9e8e485a1cda46978b58e

And here is a S.O. snippet with the same code:

```css
.active {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="400"></svg>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    radius = 32;

var circles = d3.range(20).map(function() {
  return {
    x: Math.round(Math.random() * (width - radius * 2) + radius),
    y: Math.round(Math.random() * (height - radius * 2) + radius)
  };
});

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(d3.schemeCategory20);

svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(circles)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("r", radius)
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
    .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended));

function dragstarted(d) {
  d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
}

function dragged(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
}

function dragended(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("active", false);
}
  
  var lastIndex = 0;
  
  var click = function() {
        if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return;

        var p = d3.mouse(this),
            x = p[0],
            y = p[1];
        circles[++lastIndex] = {x: x, y: y};

        svg.append('circle')
         .datum(circles[lastIndex])
           .attr('cx', x)
           .attr('cy', y)
           .attr('r', radius)
           .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(lastIndex); })
           .call(d3.drag()
                   .on("start", dragstarted)
                   .on("drag", dragged)
                   .on("end", dragended));
    };

    svg.on('click', click);

</script>
```

An even easier alternative is just changing the `dragged` function, so it doesn't rely on any bound data:

```
function dragged() {
    d3.select(this).attr("cx", d3.event.x).attr("cy", d3.event.y);
}
```

This seems to be not only the easiest, but also the best solution. As pointed out by @altocumulus in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41717131/5768908):

> Because SVGs DOM implicitly carries around positioning information in the DOM, there is no need to explicitly duplicate this information in your model, i.e. in the data bound to the DOM elements.

Comment: The use of `.datum()` is very illuminating! Re: easier alternative, what you are suggesting here is to drop the separation of the "Model"  and the "View" altogether and to just rely on a model that is embedded inside the view. Does that approach scale well for larger programs?

Comment: Well, to be honest, I'm a dataviz coder: that being said, my codes are normally small, two or three thousand lines in average. I'm not the correct person to ask if this approach scales well for larger programs, but I believe the answer is "no".

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Just added my two cents as a separate answer. Feel free to copy over any parts you like to wrap it up.

Answer (score 1):

This is an addendum to Gerardo Furtado's correct [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41710356/4235784), not a replacement nor an alternative. I decided to provide just a bit more information and share my take on this.

As pointed out by Gerardo, your assumption, that the drag behavior is not active for the newly added circles is wrong. The drag behavior is successfully attached and is active even for the new circles. The `dragged()` function will break, however, because it tries to access and assign data bound to the dragged circle. Because the newly added circles have no data bound to them, this will cause an error resulting in the drag behavior not working for these circles. As suggested by Gerardo, there are two ways around this by either binding data to the new circles using `.datum()` or getting rid of the data access in the drag handler function.

Although both approaches will work, I prefer the latter because of its simplicity. If you do not need the data for any purposes other than keeping track of the circles' positions, there is no need to keep this *model* up-to-date. Because SVGs DOM implicitly carries around positioning information in the DOM, there is no need to explicitly duplicate this information in your *model*, i.e. in the data bound to the DOM elements.

You will definitely need to use a *model* to keep track of the positional changes when it comes to plotting on a [`<canvas>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas) element. The canvas follows more of a *draw-and-forget* approach, and it is not backed by a hierarchical DOM. As compared to SVG, it does not come with a built-in notion of distinct, selectable elements and, therefore, lacks the support for binding data to elements. To be able to keep track of your elements, you have to provide a *model* backing this *view* by yourself.

Keeping this difference in mind, I think, provides more insight into why the updating of data made its way into the linked example, even though Mike Bostock is otherwise known for his rather concise code. But the Block [*Circle Dragging I*](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/22994cc97fefaeede0d861e6815a847e) does also link to [*Circle Dragging II*](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/c206c20294258c18832ff80d8fd395c3), which does the same thing using a canvas. Noticing, that both Blocks were set up on the same day, the SVG demo, i.e. *Circle Dragging I*, seems to have gotten some residual code left over from the canvas example.

Comment: Understood/Agreed. The canvas definitely requires a model. For SVG, pushing the so-called "DRY" principle and avoiding the duplication are desirable. But consider the case of a map. Might there not be information lost? Do we know that browsers will store in the SVG coordinates what we've passed them?

Comment: One additional argument why the model is not superfluous: SVG lacks layers. If we need to adjust z-depth, we need to redraw (is this accurate? can we always get away through raise/lower?). Redrawing directly from the model is saner than extracting the data into a temporary model.

Comment: On the chance you've read my last comment, I take it back :). I ran a test and it seems that raise()/lower() suffice, even in heterogeneous collections.

Comment: @Calaf This was not meant to be a generalization or a rant against the use of models. My only point is about the drag behavior, which does not require keeping track of positions yourself. The information can be derived from the DOM. For many, if not most, other cases you will, of cause, have rich data far beyond mere coordinates, which you want to bind to elements to be able to properly plot your graph. Otherwise, we wouldn't be using D3, would we?

Comment: Nothing negative about it at all. Just hoping to become better developers through discussions of compromise and sharing of experiences.